# Given the length, how can I compute the heights in cm for logo text typed in Microsoft Word?

Tags: logo

Pls see screenshot below. The contractor and I decided L. For [the logo at side of shopfront](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/153952), L = 140 cm. But don't just assume 140 cm, because I'm planning to emblazon tack another logo at top, and L varies for different logos.

Contractor requested me email him the numbers for A, B, C in cm. How do I calculate A, B, C in cm? I don't know how to do this in Adobe Illustrator, that I have.

I know 1 DeskTop Publishing point = 0.3528 mm. But I can't just multiply point by  0.3528 mm, because this doesn't account for L. For example, A  isn't 60 pt x 0.3528 mm = 21.168 mm! This is too teeny for a shopfront sign!

[image]

Comment: Graphic designers don't use Word for designing logos. It's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: You could probably have stopped at just "Graphic designers don't use Word." ;))

Comment: You **really** need to just hire a designer based on all the questions surrounding this one simple task.

Comment: FYI.. there are 72pts in 1 inch. 60pt type is less than an inch tall.

Comment: not sure why you don't just print it out and use a ruler. And as a minor warning: setting type to "60pt" might not yield a measurement that is *actually* 60pt. There is a bounding box, leading (extra space). "Space after" is also probably not "the amount of space between the baseline of one letter and top edge of the letters below it." And 14cm wide is smaller than my hand which is also probably "too teeny"

Comment: 1 last thing: the previous comments about Word may sound snarky (they are a little), but they are correct. Word should NEVER be used to submit designs. You need to submit the design in a way that the contractor can use as is. You want to be able to say "use this, but I want it 1 meter wide" With Word, you cannot even be sure the contractor is seeing the correct font. He may be wondering why you want Comic Sans for the top bit and Corsiva for the bottom bit.

Comment: Sorry, but the title of this question is funny. Logo in Word ? Better off paying some dude on Fiverr 30$ and do it "properly".

Comment: I will just point out that your going to have huge problems at a later stage. Word does not really care about precision, so when you now go and print a larger version of the logo then word can just decide to push items where ever it likes. So expect your logo to break at some point. If your okay with that. then atleast do this in PowerPoint. But really for your owns ake hire a designer to handle this for you. Even if we just count a 10 euro personal salary for your work this has allready cost you easily 50 euros. Which is enough money to do the task, stop hitting your head on the wall.

Comment: I had a senior designer colleague of me who'd often use real (physical) scale and place it on his computer screen and measure things xD

Comment: @Vikas thats fine but how do you scale the object so it is 1:1? So its kindof a extra step on the way.

Comment: @Lucian not just "Word", "logo text typed in Word" is funny :D

Comment: @asts any idea why the contractor needs those measurements?

Comment: @Vikas Because he's going to manufacture the store logo, to tack  on the wall outside my clinic??? Isn't this obvious?

Comment: I thought so but I'm still confused why he needs individual A, B, C measurements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font engines dont work in way that allow you to predict the width of the object, because it varies for each combination of letters. There is thus no way to calculate the width in advance from the size metric.*

What you do is you type out the value measure the result then scale the graphic propotionally. Now one of the defiencies of Word and inddeed most Office applications is their inability to measure text. So in this case its easiest to just print it and measure with a ruler. Then divide your desired width with the measurement, then multipley your font size by this value.

Note thet this is not going to be your last problem. The reason I wouldn't use word for this is simply it does not have a object model that conductive for this task. Word can, and randomly does all kinds of stuff that you definitely dont want to deal with, now or tomorrow.

* Because of some peculiarities in font design it is also not possible to know how high a text is without typing it and measuring it. Mainly because each letter has a different height, but also because the definition of the size metric is loose enough to not be defined strictly enough for you to do this.

**PS**: Consider hiring a designer.